# How do I correct items that are now upstart jobs but still have an entry in /etc/init.d?

Tags: 12.04, boot, upstart

How do I correct items that are now upstart jobs but still have an entry in /etc/init.d? I have an ubuntu 12.04 machine which complains in the boot.log file like:

> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start
>   S01dmesg Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use
>   the service(8) utility, e.g. service S01hostname start

How do I fix these seemingly broken services?

Answer (score 2):

The services are not broken, the reason that they still have an entry in /etc/init.d/ is for backwards compatibility. If you take a look at those scripts in /etc/init.d/ you will see they get symlinked to /lib/init/upstart-job. /lib/init/upstart-job prints that message and then processes the request (starting/stopping the service). The reason you are getting that message is because **something else** is still trying to call /etc/init.d/ rather than the proper upstart way.

To resolve this, you need to track down what is using the old method, and fix it to use the new upstart method.